# Optimizing SQLite multiple LIKE search for iOS

Tags: ios, regex, sqlite, sql-like

I'm executing an SQLite select statement with several LIKE clauses in an iPhone application. The statements resemble the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE name LIKE 'Smith %' 
OR name LIKE '% Smith %' 
OR name LIKE 'Smith_%' 
OR name LIKE '% Smith_%';
```

The execution currently takes about 0.5 seconds on my laptop and about 2 seconds on the device. I can't index the "name" column of "mytable" because of space constraints.

Each of the LIKE clauses is quite similar - if one fails, it's likely they each will. So I'd like to group these together some how to optimize my search.

Can this be done, say via REGEXP? If so, how and is REGEXP enabled by default?

Edit. I'm trying statements along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name REGEXP '[ _]?Smith[ _,]';
```

Comment: I think you're right on about REGEXP... SQLite doesn't provide an implementation of it by default, so it would only exist if you wrote a user function for it (or if there's one provided in the iOS implementation of it). And, unfortunately, the only optimizations I can think of would rely on the column being indexed.

Comment: @All: I've made some progress with this, in fact all the way through. If there's interest I'll post here. One thing - calling `regcomp` from `regex.h` to generate an internal regexpression is expensive (luckily `regexec` is fast). In my case the internal regex won't change during the course of a query, so I cache this after one `regcomp` call. That makes a /massive/ difference.

Comment: Indices won't generally work with `%...%` constructs, so it will most likely won't work with `regexp` even if it was available. You're stuck with a full table scan.

Comment: @Blindy: Maybe, although REGEX is now working great for me as I can ditch `%`. I just need to fold 4 or 5 similar LIKE operators into one operator and so far so good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite actually has a full text search engine built in. You may want to consider using it.

http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1

Comment: Right. That might be overkill for my needs, REGEX seems to be working OK. When it doesn't I'll head to FTS3/4.

Comment: @SK9: I encourage you to experiment with FTS. It's crazy fast.

Comment: Is FTS enabled by default? I exec `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE enrondata1 USING fts3(content TEXT);` and try to populate the table with inserts but no go.

Comment: @SK9 - Last I knew, it was not enabled by default. But, that's easy to fix. SQLite is a single file of source that you can include in your project.